# Passing JSON String to Thymeleaf HTML

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to pass this String to the HTML and access its properties with thymeleaf:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView getHome(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("myjson", "{indexid: \"42\", city: \"Flin Flon\"}");
    return mv;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<p th:text="${myjson}"></p>
```

This returns: `{indexid: "42", city: "Flin Flon"}`

```
<p th:text="${myjson.city}"></p>
```

This returns: `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "myjson.city"`

I have tried the following as well:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = "{\"indexid\": \"42\", \"city\": \"Flin Flon\"}";
JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
mv.addObject("myjson", actualObj);
```

And it produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding json strings onto the model.  Instead you should add a real Java object with the same properties.  For example:

```
public class Location {
  String id;
  String city;

  public Location(String id, String city) {
    this.id = id;
    this.city = city;
  }

  // Add your getters and setters
}
```

Then, if you add that object to your model:

```
mv.addObject("location", new Location("42", "Flin Flon"));
```

You'll be able to access that object in your html:

```
ID: <span th:text="${location.id}" /><br />
City: <span th:text="${location.city}" />
```